# Count Method Throwing 500 error

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I have got into strenge situation. I want to know count of Fetch based on daily, weekly, monthly and All time. In the Datastore, the count is about 2,368,348. Whenever I try to get the count either by Model or GqlQuery I get a 500 error. When rows are less, the code below is working fine.

Can any guru correct me or tell me right solution, please? I am using Python.

The Model:

```
class Fetch(db.Model):
    adid = db.IntegerProperty()
    ip = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Stats Codes:

```
adid = cgi.escape(self.request.get('adid'))
...
query = "SELECT __key__ FROM Fetch WHERE adid = " + adid  + " AND date >= :1"  
rows = db.GqlQuery( query, monthlyDate)
fetch_count = 0
for row in rows:
   fetch_count = fetch_count + 1
self.response.out.write( fetch_count)
```

Comment: Have a look in the logs. You will be getting a deadlineexceeded error. What you are attempting will not work in a front end request.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your query is taking longer than GAE allows a query to run (typically ~60 seconds). From the [count() documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_count):

> Unless the result count is expected to be small, it is best to specify a limit argument; otherwise the method will continue until it finishes counting or times out.

From the [Request Timer documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#The_Request_Timer):

> A request handler has a limited amount of time to generate and return a response to a request, typically around 60 seconds. Once the deadline has been reached, the request handler is interrupted.

If a `DeadlineExceededError` is being raised, this is your problem. If you need to run this query consider using [Backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/) in GAE. With Backends there is no time limit for generating and returning a request.